# How to reference a CSS selector defined for an element?

Tags: html, css

If I have a selector defined for `input:show_invalid`

```
<style>
input:show_invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

When I reference it in this HTML, the input does not show as red:

```
<html>
  <input type='text' class='input:show_invalid'/>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the HTML class attribute?

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS code, classes are marked by a `.`, not a `:` at the beginning. In the HTML code, you just write the class name into the `class` atrribute - without the dot or anything else.

so your code has to be

```css
input.show_invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
  <input type='text' class='show_invalid'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things wrong with your code.

1. You're using a non-existing pseudo-class, `show_invalid`. You probably meant to use the [`invalid` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid).
2. You are targeting all `<input>` elements (not a class) with a pseudo-class `show_invalid` with your CSS selector but adding the entire string `input:show_invalid` as a class in your html.

You either wanted to use the `invalid` pseudo-class:

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type='email'/>
```

or to target a class:

```css
input.show_invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' class='show_invalid'/>
```

Comment: Your second example is referencing **two** classes - `input` (not previously defined here) and `show_invalid`  Only the 'show_invalid` class name is required.

Comment: @FKEinternet Hm, I guess that makes sense. I updated my answer

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. how should I specify the html class if I cannot modify the CSS, and it is written as: `input:show_invalid,
input.show_invalid {
  background-color: red;
}`

Comment: So `input:show_invalid` will never target anything because `show_invalid` is a non-existing pseudo-class. The `input.show_invalid` on the other hand will target all elements with the tag `<input>` that have a class `show_invalid`, exactly like the second example in my answer. This means you can just add the `show_invalid` class to your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input type='text' class='show_invalid'/>
```

You're already in an  element

Answer (score 0):

A class selector should precede with a period eg. specify a simple class show and access the css as

```
.show {
     background-color: red; 
}

  OR
```

if you want the styling to be same, then replace the class name to

```
class='show_invalid'
```

Hope it helps